# Did the other divine pairings have supernatural abilities?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, cloak-and-dagger

Clearly, Tyrone and Tandy have powers. They also, according to Evita's aunt, are a divine pairing destined to save the city.

Is this something that is ancillary to the fact that they have paired powers (light and darkness, attack and defense)? Evita seemed to know Tandy was Tyrone's pairing as soon as she demonstrated her abilities.

That is, did the other divine pairings have similar powers? Or is the whole divine pairing thing separate?

Comment: Good question but the powers seem ancillary based on what we saw in the season finale. There's no evidence of powers in the other pairings we saw.